# How to add shadow for customized android google maps info window

Tags: android, google-maps-markers

My custom info window view:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
        app:cardElevation="2dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="test" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

then i use it:

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_marker_title, null);
                TextView tv_title = v.findViewById(R.id.tv_title);
                tv_title.setText(arg0.getTitle());

                return v;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
                return null;

            }
        });
```

But cardview doesn't seem to have shadow as usually. Playing with cardview's elevation or translationZ does not help.

why cardview's shadow is not working on google maps?

What is the best or easiest way to give my custom info window a shadow?

Comment: Is it ok to custom map marker instead of customizing info window

Comment: @TaQuangTu do you mean putting info window inside custommarker.xml then show n hide infowindow view?

Comment: Can you set shadow background image in info window's layout? or Can you add shadow around your LinearLayout? I hope these will help you. :)

Comment: @Alif Yes! I have tried it successfully

Comment: @ModiHarsh Its doesn't work, the background image cant have same size with LinearLayout children. Since LinearLayout wrapcontent, LinearLayout will also resize with background image size.

Comment: @TaQuangTu So, how you can have a shadow inside a custom marker? by using cardview shadow?

Comment: @Alif yes, i do!